# Is there a R function to transform the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data set below. I need to transform them so that variables names are now values

```
>(p2)
   B        D        F 
  36.0    38.93    36.06
```

I need to have like below

```
p2
Col1   COl2
 B      36.0
 D      38.93
 F      36.06
```

Comment: Hey, I think what you are asking is a simple transpose `t(p2)`. You can then make your rownames as a new column and name your columns as you wish.

Comment: use `gather()` from the tidyr package

Comment: Could you add result of `dput(p2)` to your question? Is it vector, data.frame?

Comment: Try `stack(p2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gather` function from the Tidyverse :

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(p2, key = "Col1", value = "Col2")
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Could you provide the error that you get ?

Comment: Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Oh i guess you have a named vector. Could you provide the output of `class(p2)`. Maybe you just need to convert it to dataframe (if you need to) : `data.frame(p2)`. Or you could transpose it if you need a matrix, as @Steve suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(Col1= names(p2), Col2 = p2, row.names = NULL)
```

Data :

```
p2 <- c(B =36.0, D=38.93, F= 36.06)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a vector:

```
p2 <- c(B = 36, D = 38.93, F = 36.06)
```

Then enframe from package tibble could help:

```
library(tibble)
enframe(p2)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# name  value
# <chr> <dbl>
# 1 B      36  
# 2 D      38.9
# 3 F      36.1
```

You could change names using

```
enframe(p2, "Col1", "Col2")
```